# How to optimize and increase efficiency in this particular code involving floating point operation?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture, pipelining

We know that floating point operations have high latency and take many clock cycles to execute which may cause pipeline to stall! what are the different methods to optimize the following code.

```
int main()

{

 float fsum[50],a=10.45;

 int isum[100],b=20;

 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
   {

       if(i<50) 
           {
             fsum[i] = a*a;
           }
       isum[i] = b*b

   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin>>b;` No point in optimizing the FP operations

Comment: Start by getting it to compile -- the `+ =` shouldn't (presumably you intended `+=`?)

Comment: This is not a pipeline stall. It's a programmer stall.

Comment: But in all seriousness, the only way to "optimize" that code is to properly indent it so that it is more readable. There's absolutely no point in pondering about pipelining when you have IO all over the place.

Comment: What if IO was ignored and i already have the data ??????

Comment: You might look at SSE/Altivec/other SIMD extensions offered by the hardware you are running on.  They can parallelize simple floating-point operations like this quite well sometimes.

Comment: Your code performs two memset-like operations for vectors, so why not code it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, your compiler cannot be trusted to exhibit basic optimization competence, and the code it generates runs with lower performance than you were expecting based on machine limits (you're measuring performance, and you know those limits, right?), then you can start optimizing manually:

Lift loop-invariant calculation outside the loop:

```
int main()
{
  float fsum[50],a=10.45;
  float aa = a * a;
  int isum[100],b=20;
  int bb = b * b;

  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    if(i<50) {
         fsum[i] = aa;
    }
    isum[i] = bb;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Split the loop, and set the bounds to match the enclosed condition

```
int main()
{
  float fsum[50],a=10.45;
  float aa = a * a;
  int isum[100],b=20;
  int bb = b * b;

  for(int i=0; i < 50; i++)
  {
    fsum[i] = aa;
  }

  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    isum[i] = bb;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now, if the compiler can't manage to *unroll* and *vectorize* a single-level simple loop or two, then those are your problem. Go look them up.